# Getting NAN values while parsing xml using pandas

Tags: pandas, xml

I have below xml document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<MedicineResultOutput hits="1" offset="0" totalResults="90287">
    <SearchResults>
        <medicine id="1234" name="name1" lastModificationDate="2023-04-26T00:00:00Z" status="Launched">
            <CompanySource>gftr</CompanySource>
            <MainCompany>
                <Company>Com1</Company>
                <Company>Com2 Inc</Company>
                <Company>Com3 plc</Company>
            </MainCompany>
            <RegDes>
                <RegulatoryDesignation>RD1</RegulatoryDesignation>
                <RegulatoryDesignation>RD2</RegulatoryDesignation>
            </RegDes>
            <symptomPrimary>
                <symptom>symp1</symptom>
                <symptom>symp1</symptom>
                <symptom>symp3</symptom>
            </symptomPrimary>
            <ActPrim>
                <Action>actn1</Action>
                <Action>actn2</Action>
                <Action>actn3</Action>
            </ActPrim>
            <Tech>
                <Technology>tech1</Technology>
                <Technology>tech2</Technology>
            </Tech>
            <ThAreas>
                <TA>TS1</TA>
                <TA>TS2</TA>
            </ThAreas>
            <Summary>Some random summary</Summary>
            <ComSec>
                <Company>Comp23</Company>
                <Company>Comp34</Company>
            </ComSec>
            <symptomsSecondary>
                <symptom>SS2</symptom>
                <symptom>SS3</symptom>
            </symptomsSecondary>
            <ActionsSecondary>
                <Action>ACT223</Action>
                <Action>ACT567</Action>
            </ActionsSecondary>
            <AddedDate>1996-02-16T00:00:00Z</AddedDate>
        </medicine>
    </SearchResults>
</MedicineResultOutput>
```

This is the output dataframe I am looking for:

```
id    name    lastModificationDate status   CompanySource  MainCompany      RegDes    symptomPrimary        ActPrim             Tech           ThAreas     ComSec           symptomsSecondary  AddedDateActionsSecondary   AddedDate
1234  name1   023-04-26T00:00:00Z  launched  gftr     [Com1,Com2,Com3]  [rd1,rd2]  [symp1,symp2,symp3]  [actn1,actn2,actn3]  [tech1,tech2]  [TS1,TS2]  [Comp23,Comp34]   [SS2,SS3]          [ACT223,ACT567]             1996-02-16T00:00:00Z
```

This is how I am parsing:

```
df = pd.read_xml(response.text, xpath='xpath = './/medicine')
```

I am getting all column but few columns which are having multiple values like `primary, secondaryin, Technologies` are populating NAN values. What's wrong I am doing here? For the above input my output dataframe should have 3 rows for the company id=9000 because `primary, secondaryin, ActPrimary, Technologies` are having 3 different values.

Comment: We can't tell what you're doing wrong unless you tell us what you're doing. Presumably you're doing more that just reading the XML.

Comment: Can you edit your question and, first, fix your xml so it is well-formed and, second, show the **exact** expected output given your (fixed) xml?

Comment: Sorry to pile in but xpath value is also not correctly formatted.

Comment: @Jack Fleeting I have updated the input xml and also expected output

Comment: @MichaelKay. I have added the updated xml and the expected output dataframe. Basically I just want to create a pandas dataframe from this xml and if any column has multiple value then put it inside a list

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but I don't think you can get to your expected output using `read_xml()` since your xml is too nested. It can be done "by hand", that is - by parsing the xml with an xml parser and adding the data to a dataframe. It's pretty convoluted, but it does work.

I chose to do the parsing using lxml, because I believe it's better suited for this purpose than ElementTree. I'll try to explain inline, but since it involves quite a few techniques (xpath, dataframes, list manipulation and comprehension, etc.) you may have to do some more reading.

```
#import necessary libraries
from lxml import etree
import pandas as pd

#parse the response with lxml
doc = etree.XML(response.text.encode())

#build your data lists
rows = []
cols = ["d","name","lastModificationDate","status","CompanySource","AddedDate","MainCompany","RegDes","symptomPrimary","ActPrim","Tech","ThAreas","ComSec","symptomsSecondary","AddedDateActionsSecondary"]
meds = doc.xpath('//medicine')

#popluate your lists with data obtained using xpath
for med in meds:
    #the sum() method below is used to flatten the list of lists returned 
    #by the xpath expressions
    basedats = sum([med.xpath('./@*'),med.xpath('./CompanySource/text()'),med.xpath('./AddedDate/text()')],[])
    moredats = med.xpath('.//*[.//*]')

    #note: it's "extend()", not "append()"
    basedats.extend(dat.xpath('./*/text()') for dat in moredats)
    rows.append(basedats)

#finally, build your dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(rows,columns=cols)
df
```

Note that the output will be somewhat different from your expected output, because the latter is somewhat inconsistent with the sample xml.